# Turning off Bluetooth when exiting an application

Tags: android, bluetooth

As an introduction to my question, I'll tell you that I've searched around the correct way to do things but still didn't find an answer.

I saw in many questions asked in stackoverflow, that exiting applications in Android is done simply by clicking the 'home' button. I saw some people say that it is not a common use to have an 'exit' button on your app.

Here comes my question. Suppose I turn on the Bluetooth coonection in my app, so that two players can play one against each other with two phones/tablets. Now, they want to go out or they want to go on in their lives. How can I turn the Bluetooth off? is there a timeout for application that does this for me? Should I start a downtime counter to turn the Bluetooth off? What if the user decided to go out to read an SMS and then come back to the app, discovering the bluetooth is off?

In other words, what is the correct manner to deal with shuting down Bluetooth when it is not needed any more with out interfering the user?

Sorry for the long question, I just want to make myself clear.

Thanks,
AJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the onPause() method in your activity to disable bluetooth, and override the onResume() method in your activity to enable it again.

However, I would not recommend this.  For starters, it takes a good second of time to switch the hardware on/off.  Also, what if the user is using some other bluetooth connected device?  Pausing your app would cut that connection off.  What if bluetooth was already on when the user starts the app?  They probably wouldn't want your app changing that.

My recommendation is when you start your app, look and see if BT is enabled.  If it is not, prompt the user to turn it on.  If you're really set on cleaning up after yourself, you could add a checkbox to the prompt I just mentioned, that says something like "Disable it again on exit", and let them choose if they want that.

Comment: Matt, thanks! So you are suggesting prompting for turning off bluetooth in my override onpause method? This means that when my app goes into the background, the user will be prompted with this?

Comment: No, you can't have UI code in onPause().  Im suggesting leaving bluetooth on when your app pauses, unless at the beginning of your app, when turning bluetooth on, the user explicitly says they want bluetooth to go back off when the app is paused.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try and report how it went! thanks for your time!

Comment: one question though, how to achieve this when you have multiple activities in your app? I don't want to turn it off when switching activities, only when application is closed (or send to background), the thing is that onPause would be triggered when switching activities.. I know it's an old question, but nowadays it's still a valid one.